# Getting error Argument 1 missing for FacebookRedirectLoginHelper

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to the new Facebook api. I using the Facebook's own tutorial as my guide. The tutorial in the Facebook developer's site asks us that after we are redirected to from Facebook we should get a `$helper`. The code for that is given there. It is

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper();
```

But I am getting an error. It says argument 1 missing for the __construct of `FacebookRedirectLoginHelper()`. What am I doing wrong? I need it to write my paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's missing from the docs, but the first argument is the callback URL and it is required. Here's the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/blob/4.0-dev/src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php#L73).

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('https://example.com/facebook/callback');
```

Someone just [submitted a PR](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/pull/324) to fix the docs.